# What's the (subtle) difference between "once again" and "yet again"?

Tags: word-choice, differences, phrase-usage

I think they mean pretty much the same thing, but maybe the *tone* is different (or *subtext*)?

Example sentences:

> **Once again,** I went to Shibuya, one of the busiest pedestrian
> intersections in Japan, and began a leisure afternoon of
> *girlwatching*.
>
> **Yet again,** I went to Shibuya, one of the busiest pedestrian
> intersections in Japan, and began a leisure afternoon of
> *girlwatching*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They both technically mean the same thing.

I would say that the use of the word "yet" expresses an attitude of irritation or displeasure at the act of "girl-watching" again.

On the contrary the use of "once again" is neutral and doesn't express a positive or negative attitude.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder what word would give the sentence a positive attitude.