# Are there subtle differences between "Again, ..." and "Once again, ..."?

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expression-choice

For example, is this:

> **Once again,** I went to Shibuya and began a leisurely afternoon of people watching.

different from this?

> **Again,** I went to Shibuya and began a leisurely afternoon of people watching.

Or they mean pretty much the same?

Comment: I thought we already did this one?

Comment: @Xanne Really? Do you have the link?

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/418074/whats-the-subtle-difference-between-once-again-and-yet-again.  It was closed; however, there's an answer.  You posted the question.

Comment: @Xanne The question is a bit different. That's "Yet again" vs "Once again."

Comment: just combine them into one post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Again*** can be used to refer activities taking place repeatedly. For example:

> he's again and again trying to kiss me.

***Once again*** is used for something that is happening one more time.

> once again, he tried to kiss me.

Comment: I'm glad that you want to participate,  but we prefer longer answers that support their claims with sources. It's also preferable to format your answer so that people can read it easily. The [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) has a lot of good advice for doing this.